# Why is PTR needed in DNS, instead of using a service record or an MX record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, reverse-dns, ptr-record

Why would an organization with an email system have a requirement that a system sending email to it needs a PTR reverse lookup DNS record of the IP address of the sending email server?

Can the receiving system not match the IP address of the sending system with the IP address in a service SRV, SPF, or A record?

Comment: Using a PTR is a custom that was established 25 years ago before SRV and SPF records existed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have control of the PTR record, your ISP does. As such, the backwards lookup from the IP address to a name that your ISP vouches for is another indication that your address actually belongs to you. It is one of the earliest steps in detecting spam, if the server name provided in the EHLO message doesn't match the PTR there's probably an issue. I think that part of the reason there is such extensive use of the PTR record is that the domain in the HELO / EHLO record is a relatively recent requirement; it is useful to have something to compare against when the `From:` address comes up.

That said, it is sort of a weak indication. That's the reason that SPF and DKIM/DMARC evolved, as a more certain way to ensure that the mail is coming from who it says it's coming from, and that (in the case of DKIM) it hasn't been tampered with along the way.

Just as a side note, I'll remind you that there is no IP address in an MX record; MX is the name of a mailserver, you then have to look up the address via the A or AAAA record. And outbound mail doesn't necessarily come from the domain's mail server; you could have several different mail sources, an in-house mail server and a clutch of web servers, say.

Answer (score 2):

Forwards confirmed reverse DNS is an old origin check used to combat spam that far pre-dates SPF

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS